# Can't resolve maven dependency with beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java and bigtable-client-core

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to run Java code from a Maven project that uses both beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java and bigtable-client-core, and I cannot get it to properly reconcile dependencies amongst these two. When I run and attempt to create a BigtableDataClient, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TE_HEADER
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit> (Utils.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<clinit> (NettyChannelBuilder.java:72)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress (NettyChannelProvider.java:37)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress (NettyChannelProvider.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress (ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel (InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:242)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel (InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:198)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel (InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:185)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create (ClientContext.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStub.create (EnhancedBigtableStub.java:151)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.create (BigtableDataClient.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.create (BigtableDataClient.java:130)
 ...
```

I can only conclude this is due to an issue with version conflict on the relevant libraries (either grpc-netty or grpc-netty-shaded); I'm using 1.17 for grpc-netty and 1.23 for grpc-netty-shaded. I've tried using dependencyManagement to force the use of version 1.23.0 for both grpc-netty and grpc-netty-shaded, and then tried 1.17 for both, but this doesn't help. I've also tried using earlier versions of both the Beam runners and bigtable-client-core, and this doesn't help either.

The relevant Maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
       <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
       <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
      <artifactId>bigtable-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I look at the code for Utils.java (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blame/master/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/Utils.java), and I don't see any evidence that I'd be using any earlier version that might not have this constant (it's been there since version 1.7).

I'm completely baffled what the issue is here. How do I identify the dependency conflict? Is there another way I can find what version of the class Maven is actually looking at here?

Comment: I checked Beam master, and it seems that beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform depends on bigtable-client-core version 1.8. Have you tried using that dependency? Or do you need the more recent 1.12?

Comment: Best way to investigate is to run `mvn dependency:tree`, and then probably looking for references to grpc-core. I agree it appears that a grpc-core version older than 1.7 is being used. In general, we recommend using maven-enforcer with requireUpperBoundDeps . See [our example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/e281c75b2a0fab2b44f177defb39a017decbb101/examples/pom.xml#L106-L123).

Comment: Do you ran the command aforementioned (mvn dependency:tree)? I also think that the cause is/was  the older version library.

Comment: @wrp How did you get it to work?